# the pattern of `table = malloc(sizeof *table * count)`

Tags: c

I create such a program which try to reduce the efforts of maintenance using code structure `table = malloc(sizeof *table * 3);`

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct today {
    int date;
    char weekday;
};

int main(void)
{   
    struct today *table;

    table = malloc(sizeof *table * 3);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        table[0].date = 20181022;
        table[0].weekday = 'M';
    }
    printf("%d, %c", table[0].date, table[0].weekday);

    free(table);

    return 0;
}
```

It works and print:

```
In [25]: !./a.out                                                                                                 
20181022, M
```

Nonetheless, the compiler remind multiple lines of warning

```
In [27]: !cc draft.c                                                                                              
draft.c:12:13: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)'
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    table = malloc(sizeof *table * 3);
            ^
draft.c:12:13: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
draft.c:14:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         ^
draft.c:14:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                ^
draft.c:14:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                       ^
draft.c:21:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    free(table);
    ^
2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
```

Within the "2 warnings and 3 errors generated.", which one I can ignore?

Comment: "should I refactor codes to clear all the warnings?" is that rhetorical question ? Also "2 warnings and 3 errors generated.", ***errors*** !!! "It works perfectly" I will not say that your program "work".

Comment: sorry about my bad expression, which one of them  could be ignored? @Stargateur

Comment: What header is `malloc()` declared in? (None of them should be ignored, they should be fixed)

Comment: "which one of them could be ignored?" No one.

Comment: *"note: include the header <stdlib.h>"* And declare the variable `i`.

Comment: but this malloc style reduce typo and protect from extra maintenance  efforts. @Shawn

Comment: The errors have nothing to do with the `malloc` style.

Comment: It's accepted in C11 @user3386109

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h> int i;` missing.

Comment: ***"which one I can ignore?"*** Answer ***NONE***. Do not accept code until it compiles cleanly without a single warning. You can learn as much C just by listening to what your compiler is telling you as you can from most tutorials.

Comment: The compiler tells you very clearly what the bugs are. Just read the compiler output and fix the code. "note: include the header <stdlib.h>" means include the header stdlib.h. "error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'" means you need to declare the variable `i`. Just do as it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include stdlib.h and delcare i as an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct today {
    int date;
    char weekday;
};

int main(void)
{   
    struct today *table;

    table = malloc(sizeof *table * 3);

    if(table == NULL)
    {
        //Memory allocation failed
        //TODO: Handle this somehow.
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        table[0].date = 20181022;
        table[0].weekday = 'M';
    }
    printf("%d, %c", table[0].date, table[0].weekday);

    free(table);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be good to eliminate the failure to **validate** the allocation and provide error reporting with `perror()` in case of failure. E.g. `if (table == NULL) { perror ("malloc-table"); return 1; }` See also: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: just for fun your program doesn't check the return value from malloc and you are casting malloc

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? I'm not sure that was warranted. The information provided was correct. A better course may be to encourage inclusion of error checking and a note about not casting `malloc`.

Comment: Apologies, I'm mostly a c++ dev and was not aware implicit promotion from void* is allowed in C. As for validating the result of malloc i would argue that such a thing is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: No big deal. `malloc` returns `void*` which is assignable to/from any pointer type without a cast in C. The biggie is that `malloc` can (and does) fail, so you really need to check `if (table == NULL)` and handle the error after allocating with `malloc`.